# HTML AutoFocus in a input field with value

Tags: html, text, autofocus

first, if anyone has another more specific and better title for this question please tell me and I'll change. I've never been good at using Google so...

I'm currently using following code to create an input field

```
<input name="igname" type="text" maxlength="40" autofocus="autofocus" value="Hi">
```

It works fine, but there's just one problem -> the cursor is on the left, I want it to be on the right but I don't have any idea how to do so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First idea

> Use `style='text-align:right'` to change the text align.

### PUT THE CURSOR TO THE END

To put the cursor to the end of editable element, use this : [tested function](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/move-cursor-to-end-of-input/) | [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AfTbL/4/)
For the fiddle, it works great on Chrome, but in FF, you have to give focus to the element because the IFRAME haven't got focus by default!

```js
moveCursorToEnd = function(el, focused) {
console.log('go');
if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
    el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
} else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
    if(!focused)
        el.focus();
    var range = el.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(false);
    range.select();
}
if(!focused)
    el.focus();
}

onbodyload = function() {
    elem = document.getElementById('totheend');
    moveCursorToEnd(elem);
}
```

```
<body onload='onbodyload()'>...
<input class='totheend' onfocus="if(typeof moveCursorToEnd != 'undefined') moveCursorToEnd(this, true)" name="igname" type="text" maxlength="40" autofocus="autofocus" value="Hi" >
```

Comment: samitha is right. I want to have the cursor to be on the right, not on the left like you see on my ScreenShot

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Since I have never really used Javascript, could you please explain me how to use the function exactly? I tried it that way, but it didn't work http://pastebin.com/Yum2D7Kq

Answer (score 2):

JoDev's answer does not seem to work with FF and could be simplified. el is the DOM element representing the input.

```
function moveCursorToEnd(el) {
    'use strict';
    var index=el.value.length;
    el.focus();
    el.setSelectionRange(index,index);
}
```